# Django rest framework RetrieveAPIView not working: 404

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I try to view an item in django with `RetrieveAPIView` for URL like:

`http://142.93.130.167:1080/api/videos/1`

I get `404 not found`.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^videos/$', views.VideosList.as_view(), name="videos list"),
url(r'^videos/<int:pk>', views.VideoDetail.as_view(), name="video details"),
```

[full source](https://github.com/scaltro/youtubeapp/blob/master/myupload/urls.py)

Where am I wrong?

`django 1.11`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at least you have a mix of supported trailing `/` behavior. You better choose any of them: whether trailing `/` is required (as it is in the first regex) or not (in the second regex). Compare it to your `APPEND_SLASH` value in [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-APPEND_SLASH).

Another thing is that your URL-pattern names mismatch DRF naming style (see [examples](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)):

- `videos list` in DRF style would be `videos-list`
- `video details` -> `videos-detail`

this should help DRF determining their URLs in HyperlinkedSerializer and so on.

One more point:
in your URL patterns you use regex URL-patterns (`url()` function) with placeholders supported by [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/urls/#path) patterns. Don't mix them.
Choose this

```
url(r'^videos/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.VideoDetail.as_view(), name="video details"),
```

or this

```
path('videos/<int:pk>', views.VideoDetail.as_view(), name="video details"),
```

`path` is the recommended way since `url` is deprecated already.

So, my advice is:

on Django >= 2.0

- `url()` -> `path`
- remove `/$`
- rename patterns to match DRF naming style

on Django < 2.0

- fix `url()` regexs
- remove `/$` or add to each pattern
- still, rename patterns to match DRF naming style

Comment: problem of path is : i can't import it in django 1.11.15 -- return me this error : from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name path

Comment: Use appropriate regex then. You have two options, one of them is unavailable at your version... which means... What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is because there is no slash after the url. Could you use the following api and see

```
http://142.93.130.167:1080/api/videos/1/
```

If this works then it means it was because of the append-slash issue. Do read about it in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#append-slash)

UPDATE:

Seems like you need to update your *urls.py*

```
url(r'^videos/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', views.VideoDetail.as_view(), name="video details"),
```

Could you try now?

Comment: thanks @argo , but not working .. now i added slash other the url and problem is not fixed

Comment: I have updated the code, seems like your _urls.py_ file needs to be updated. Could you try this code and see?